# Power Bi Extract a Column value based on some another field in different Table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I have a Power BI table with some columns as given below:

```
Table1 - Columns(Project, Program, Name, Attribute, ID)
```

Example of table1:

[image]

Now I have a different measure which is used to view Power BI report. It also has some fields as given below:

```
Measure1 - Columns(Project, Name, Attribute, and few more)
```

Example of Measure:

[image]

Now I want to add ID (which is available in Table1) as Measure1 is being used to view report. How can I display ID based upon Name and Project.

Can anyone guide or help how to solve it?

Comment: its not clear what do you want achive. Table1 and Measure1 are both a table?  Edit your question and add some dummy data and desired output;

Comment: @msta42a I have updated question. Kindly check now

Answer (score 0):

If you can do this in your source Database using left join between this 2 tables.
If not, then you can use virtual relationship in DAX:

```
Display_ID = CALCULATE(min(Table1[ID]), TREATAS(VALUES(Table1[Project]), Measure1[Project]),  TREATAS(VALUES(Table1[Name]), Measure1[Name]))
```

[image]